# Binary Optimization Problems that can be easily solved?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, binary-programming

As far as I have researched, even linear programs with binary constraints on the decision variables are in general NP hard.

However, I wounder if there are some (non-trivial) binary optimization problems (not necessarily linear) with special structure out there, that can be solved efficiently (i.e. polynomial time)?

With "trivial" I mean something like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{x} \quad&x^T x \\
\text{s.t.}\quad&x\in\{0,1\}^n
\end{align}\tag{1}
$$

where its obvious that the optimal solution of $(1)$ is the zero vector.

**Question**: What are some difficult binary optimization problems, that still can be solved efficiently? And, if that is know, what makes them "easy" to solve?

Comment: linear objective, totally unimodular constraint matrix